# WooCommerce product pages are almost blank

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce 3.2.5 on Wordpress 4.9 with the WC-compatible XClean Theme.

All my products are variable. When I click on "Select Options" from the shop page or the products slider on the home page, the /products/foo page which loads contains nothing but a large image of the product (or placeholder as we don't have our photography yet) - there is no description, no attribute selection, and no add to cart. I just added a simple product, and the result is the same.

Wile there is an outdated template warning, it's only for the mini-cart template, not product templates.

https://wildcatcoffee.co.nz/shop/

Comment: You need to check your logs. You have php fatal error which breaks the page

Comment: Do you have a woocommerce subfolder in your theme folder ?.